# Dynamic dropping of table column in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to add or delete a column in `table2` when a record is inserted in `table1(groups-id, title, rateperkg)`. The name of the new `table2`-column name will be same as `title` field inserted.

I was able to add the column successfully but could perform deleting. It shows undefined value but I defined it. Please help me.

Below have screenshot:

[image: add function]

[image: delete function]

[image: Error]

```
Table2 - pricings(id, product_id)
Table1 - groups(id, title)
```

The groups title should get inserted as new column name in pricings table and deleting.

Answer (score 0):

In your first screenshot you use the `use` in the callback/function, you also need to add this to the latest screenshot. Take a look at how PHP scopes work, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

You can use this with this code:

```
Schema::table('pricings', function (Blueprint $table) use ($subgroup) {
    $table->dropcolumn($subgroup);
});
```

This will set the scope for `$subgroup` in the callback/function you defined.

See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php for this example: #3

```
// Inherit $message
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

Comment: thanks for your explaination.. now the variable has been set but now i  am getting another error

Comment: `"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP '["Medium"]'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table pricings drop ["Medium"])"`

Comment: but column name Medium is exist in pricings table